# How can I enable all warnings when using ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

can somebody tell me how can I enable all the warnings when building with the ndk?
I have tried looking on the internet but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Or any other flags that you want to provide to compiler.

If you have `Application.mk` you can add there instead:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

So it will apply to all modules you build.

Comment: Thanks. I have multiple modules in my project that will be compiled, each with it's Android.mk. Do I have to add to all Android.mks?

Comment: @user72182718 just added update about Application.mk